# Proving a sequence in a compact set contains a point that converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, compactness

Let $E$ be a compact set and let $f$ be continuous on $E$. Suppose there is a sequence {$x_n$}$_{n=1 \to \infty}$ of such points of E such that $\lvert f(x_n) \rvert < \frac{1}{n}$ for each $n$. Explain why there is a point y of E such that $f(y)=0$

So basically, I'm given that $f(x_n)$ is compact. Also since $E$ is compact, there is a point in $E$ (call it $y$) where $y$ is in $E$ and {$x_n$}$_{n=1 \to \infty}$ converges to $y$. (*These are just my thoughts*)

Intuitively I know that $\lvert f(x_n) \rvert < \frac{1}{n}$ and if $\exists y$ in $x_n$, where $f(y)=0$, but how do I show this ?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\{x_n\}$ may not converge. Since $E$ is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent *subsequence* $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that converges to some element $y \in K$. Now apply continuity.

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$, then find some $\delta$ such that $\lvert f(x_{n_k})-f(x_{n_y}) \rvert < \epsilon$ if $\lvert x_{n_k} - x_{n_y} \rvert < \delta$?

Comment: More like, if $x_{n_k} \to y$, then $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(y)$.

Comment: Then since $\lvert f(y) \rvert < \lvert f(x_n) \rvert < \frac{1}{n}$, $f(y)$ converges to $0$?